# reading a specific line of a text file in R

Tags: r, file, line

I have a file in txt format separated by tabs. 
The question that I have is that if its possible to jump to an specific line, but without using a for loop, for example if I want to jump to the second line I have done this:

```
  fileName="table.txt"
  con=file(fileName,open="r")
  for (i in 1:2){
      ctable<-readLines(con,n=1)
  }
```

but I dont want to use a for loop, how I can do that?
Thanks

Comment: you can `readLines(con,n=x)`, discarding the output, where `x` is the number of lines you want to skip; the next line read will be the `x+1`st.

Answer (score 4):

Use `read.table()` and provide the number of lines to skip in the `skip` argument. Type in `?read.table` at the console for more information on additional arguments and wrappers that you can use.